# masking alphanumeric strings to similar format

Tags: python

i'm trying to impose a format on an alphanumeric string where digits become all 9's and the alphabets become A's.
e.g. N43563 == A999
e.g2. dhfgb85fb == AAAAA99AA
something along these lines
pytho based. i have tried regex but it was a bit confusing for me which is why i'm now asking for assistance

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> result1 = re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', 'A', 'dhfgb85fb')
>>> result2 = re.sub('[0-9]', '9', result1)
>>> result2
'AAAAA99AA'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `re` for that, if you only want to replace each `digit` for a `9` and each `letter` for an `A` then you can do this:

```py
sample = ['N43563', 'dhfgb85fb']

for s in sample:
    new_s = ''.join(
        '9' if letter.isdigit() else 'A' for letter in s
    )
    print(new_s)

>>> A99999
>>> AAAAA99AA
```